# Force Photos to update to iCloud on Mac

Tags: icloud, photos

Is there some way to force Photos on Mac to sync with iCloud? Many times when I import pictures they do not get uploaded to iCloud. It's very flakey. I checked my iCloud storage space and I have plenty of remaining space so I don't know what the cause could be. I've lately been resorting to uploading the images to Google Drive then downloading them to my phone.

EDIT: I believe I found the cause. If the photos are too big in size (over 2MB) they won't sync. Is there some setting to adjust this?

Comment: Connecting to wifi and power would work. Also leave photos app open. Also to see the progress, of to the bottom of all the photos and videos. Make sure it is not paused.

Comment: Also see in preferences if you’ve turned on iCloud and photo stream. https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204264